# NSRegularExpression and repeating pattern

Tags: ios, regex, xcode

I am writing an app that is receiving message blocks via TCP. A message block is composed of the following:

- a fixed header `<<:--!!`
- 6 digits that give the length of the message
- the message itself

It sound logical to use NSRegularExpression to extract the messages from the data received, so I ended up with the following code in playground, implementing the processing of a string of data received:

```
import UIKit

struct Constants {
    static let messageHeaderPattern = "<<:--!!(\\d{6})(.+)"
}

let receivedData = "<<:--!!000010My message"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: Constants.messageHeaderPattern, options: [])  // Define the regular expression
let range = NSMakeRange(0, receivedData.characters.count)                          // Define the range (all the string)
let matches = regex.matchesInString(receivedData, options: [], range: range)       // Get the matches

print("Number of matches: \(matches.count)")

for match in matches {

    let locationOfMessageLength = match.rangeAtIndex(1).location
    let expectedLengthOfMessage = Int(receivedData.substringWithRange(Range(start: receivedData.startIndex.advancedBy(locationOfMessageLength),
        end: receivedData.startIndex.advancedBy(locationOfMessageLength + 6))))

    let locationOfMessage = match.rangeAtIndex(2).location
    let lengthOfMessage = match.rangeAtIndex(2).length
    let data = receivedData.substringWithRange(Range(start: receivedData.startIndex.advancedBy(locationOfMessage),
        end: receivedData.startIndex.advancedBy(locationOfMessage + lengthOfMessage)))

    // data contains "My message"

}
```

This code works well, but only if there is one message in the string. To make it work for multiple messages, I changed the regular expression:

```
static let messageHeaderPattern = "(?:<<:--!!(\\d{6})(.+))+"
```

and the received data:

```
let receivedData = "<<:--!!000010My message<<:--!!000014Second message"
```

But there is still only one match, and data contains `My message<<:--!!000014Second message`.

What is wrong with my regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message could even contain `<<:--!!\d{6}` so I don't think you will be able to do this with regex alone, so the safe solution is.

1. regex for `^<<:--!!(\d{6})` to extract the length N
2. substring out N characters starting from the 13th
3. repeat

If you want to live dangerously and are confident that `<<:--!!\d{6}` will never occur in the message then this regex will do the trick.

```
(?<=<<:--!!\d{6})(.*?)(?=<<:--!!\d{6}|$)
```

Just remember it *will mess up if the delimiter occurs inside the string*, you should use the method in my first example to be safe.

Comment: This is indeed my plan B, but I wanted first to check if it would be possible to do it exclusively via a regular expression. I will wait a little more for any additional answer before proceeding.

Comment: If you could do back references inside curly braces then this would do the trick <<:--!!(\d{6})(.{\1}) but I don't think thats possible in regex :(

Comment: I added an additional regex if you are sure `<<:--!!\d{6}` will never occur in the message

Comment: Brilliant! This "look behind" operator perfectly makes the trick. I understand the risk if `<<:--!!\d{6}`appears in the content of a message, but I consider that it is very unlikely to happen, and the consequences not severe. Thanks!

Comment: To be safe you can also grab the \d{6} out and check your message length matches. Then you will know if something weird happened.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the pattern `static let messageHeaderPattern = "<<:--!!(\\d{6})(.+?)(?!<<:--!!)"`

Comment: With this pattern, I indeed get 2 matches. But the message is not extracted correctly, I get "M" on the first loop, and "S" on the second one, so only the first character of my message.  I guess this is caused by `+?` which means _1 or more times. Match as few times as possible._

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering the message itself more, so the (.*) not include the second message in it:

```
"(?:<<:--!!(\\d{6})([a-zA-Z ]+))"
```

Comment: This is not going to work, as a message can contain any data, even binary data.